# How to get user_id within BuddyPress email template to use for PHP functions

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am trying to get the user_id for the recipient from within a BuddyPress email template without much success. I have tried the following email tokens from the Codex, none of which appear to be available in the context I'm using: `{{user.id}}` `{{original_activity.user_id}}`

There doesn't seem to be a global token available, like:  `{{recipient.userid}}`

Does anyone know how to add the user_id as a global token, or is there an alternative way to get the user_id of the recipient user from within a BuddyPress email template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a solution that works as follows:

```
function add_user_id_to_email_tokens($tokens,$property_name,$transform,$email)
{
    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $tokens['recipient.email'] );
    $user_id=$user->ID;
    $tokens['recipient.userid'] = $user_id;
    return $tokens;
}
add_filter('bp_email_get_tokens','add_user_id_to_email_tokens',10,4);
```

I am now able to use the token `{{recipient.userid}}` in all BP email templates as a global token.